# Heroku 404 only some static files in Public folder

Tags: node.js, heroku

I get a console log of 404 cannot find file after deploying to Heroku.

In my app.js I have:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

In the public folder I have sub folders:

```
- public
-- css
--- styles.css
-- js
--- custom.js
-- php
--- db_connect.php
--- load_posts.php
```

The page loads with the css and js code and works as expected but the php is 404. I am calling the load_posts.php from the custom.js via ajax on page load but it is not working. If I Open the app on Heroku and add php/load_posts.php tot he URL it just downloads the file so it seems to be there.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Any ideas?

Comment: php/load_posts.php downloads the file. This is correct behaviour for a static file server. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike I am looking for the page to load data from a mysql database on page load.Should I move it out of public?

Comment: If you have the logic to load data in your PHP file, then it won't work with a static server. Read up on client and server-side languages. PHP is processed on the server and is often an alternative to node, not served through it. You might find [Heroku with PHP](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php) useful.

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike, I know PHP and am trying to learn node as an alternative to use some cool features. I have been trying to use node mysql to load data from a database, which works but want to get it to a client side script. Socket.io works but also crashes if called from another browser. I'll keep researching, I think my brain keeps going to PHP paradigms.